# SQL Query returning the last ID based on a value from another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the last ID for a "MenuItem.MenuID" because it is the latest version of that type,in saying that there are multiple Menu.Names per Market. How do I get a latest Id per Menu Per Market with all the items in that menu?

```
SELECT 
    MenuItem.MenuId, Menu.Name, MenuItem.ProductId, Product.Name,
    MenuItem.Count,Menu.MenuTypeId, MenuType.MarketId, Available,
    StandardItem,  UnitsPerPackage, ItemWeighting, Product.Disabled, ExtraItem
FROM MenuItem 
JOIN Menu 
  ON MenuItem.MenuId = Menu.Id 
JOIN ProducT 
  ON MenuItem.ProductId = Product.Id 
JOIN MenuType
  ON MenuType.Id = MENU.MenuTypeId
WHERE MenuType.Disabled = 0
  AND product.Disabled = 0 
  AND MENU.NAME = 'a generic menu' 
  AND MenuType.MarketId = 1
ORDER BY 
    MarketId,
    MENU.ID,
    MenuTypeId;
```

Comment: What database are you using, say, SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
  MenuItem.MenuId, Menu.Name, MenuItem.ProductId, Product.Name,
  MenuItem.Count,Menu.MenuTypeId, MenuType.MarketId, Available,
  StandardItem,  UnitsPerPackage, ItemWeighting, Product.Disabled, ExtraItem
FROM 
  MenuItem 
  INNER JOIN Menu ON MenuItem.MenuId = Menu.Id 
  INNER JOIN ProducT ON MenuItem.ProductId = Product.Id 
  INNER JOIN MenuType ON MenuType.Id = MENU.MenuTypeId
WHERE
  MenuType.Disabled=0 AND product.Disabled=0 
  AND MENU.NAME = 'a generic menu' AND MenuType.MarketId=1
ORDER BY 
  MarketId, MENU.ID, MenuTypeId
```

**UPDATE:**

You could possibly use common table expressions something like this if you want to return the top for each market:

```
WITH MyMenus AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MenuType.MarketId ORDER BY Menu.Id, Menu.MenuTypeId) AS rowNumber
   FROM MenuItem
     INNER JOIN Menu ON MenuItem.MenuId = Menu.Id
     INNER JOIN Product ON MenuItem.ProductId = Product.Id
     INNER JOIN MenuType ON MenuType.Id = Menu.MenuTypeId
   WHERE
     MenuType.Disabled=0 AND product.Disabled=0
     AND Menu.Name = 'a generic menu'
)
SELECT *
FROM MyMenus
WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

Comment: It returns only The top Id, so the last menu,but there are 10 menus per 10 markets and each  menu has 8-10 items inside,this returns the first item only. I need it to return multiple menus (and only the last menu id) for that menu. Thank you

Comment: I need It to return a top value per menu per market. Thanks anyway for trying

Comment: Can you generate and upload a SQL script of the schema and some sample data so I can duplicate your exact problem and try to solve it?